# NDK-STACK stack frame not useful

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

Ndk-stack give this output:

> Build fingerprint: 'intel/inet_alc5651_64/inet_alc5651:5.1.1/LMY47V/inet-soft0504291459:userdebug/release-keys'
>   pid: 30534, tid: 30557, name: GLThread 2273  >>> xxx <<<
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x18
>   Stack frame #00 pc 001a26a3  [anon:Mem_0x20000000]
>   Stack frame #01 pc 0000302f  [anon:Mem_0x10002002]

It is not obvious. I could not find error memory address. Why is this output like above ?

Comment: how do you launch `ndk-stack`?

Comment: this is the command that i used:  `adb logcat | ./ndk-stack -sym /Users/Gokhan/Desktop/Wordz2/proj.android-studio/app/obj/local/armeabi`

Comment: did you try another architecture versions? like armeabi-v7a?